# Google Apps Script - Creating Calendar Events with Appointment Color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

So I have a script that creates calendar events just fine, I am now trying to have the appointment color red without success. What is the best way to do this? Here is a portion of the code that I am currently using.

Here is the revised code that is now working!

```
function createCalendarEvent(eventObject) {
  //Get a calendar object by opening the calendar using the
  //calendar id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
    //var startTime = eventObject.startDate+" "+eventObject.startTime
   //var endTime = eventObject.endDate+" "+eventObject.endTime

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(GLOBAL.calendarId),
      //The title for the event that will be created
      title = eventObject.eventTitle,
      //The start time and date of the event that will be created
      startTime1 = moment(eventObject.startDate+" "+eventObject.startTime).toDate(),
      //The end time and date of the event that will be created ---moved up
      APLength = eventObject.AppLength1;
  //an options object containing the description and guest list
  //for the event that will be created
  var comboDescription = title+" in "+ eventObject.county +" is interested in a "+eventObject.deckStyle+". The referral source was "+eventObject.referral+". "+" Their email address is "+eventObject.Cemail+"."+" They can be reached at "+eventObject.phone1+" "+eventObject.phone2+" "+eventObject.Gdescription+" "+eventObject.Qdescription;
  var options = {
    description : comboDescription,
    guests: eventObject.Cemail,
    location: eventObject.location,
  };

    if(APLength=="1 hour") {var endTime1 = moment(eventObject.startDate+" "+eventObject.startTime).add(1, 'h').toDate()};
    if(APLength=="2 hour") {var endTime1 = moment(eventObject.startDate+" "+eventObject.startTime).add(2, 'h').toDate()};
    //////Send a reminder email
     //MailApp.sendEmail ("-----------", "New Appointment with "+title, "I have added the following information to your calender. The appointment range is "+moment(startTime1).format("dddd, MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")+" till "+ moment(endTime1).format("dddd, MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")+" See the following appointment details....."+comboDescription);
  try {
    //create a calendar event with given title, start time,
    //end time, and description and guests stored in an 
    //options argument
    //calendarEvent.setColor(11);
    //eventObject.colorId: 11
    var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime1, endTime1, options)
    event.setColor("11")
     //var event = Calendar.Events.insert(title, startTime1, endTime1, options)
    //CalendarApp.event.setColor("10")


    } catch (e) {
      //delete the guest property from the options variable, 
      //as an invalid email address with cause this method to 
      //throw an error.
      delete options.guests
      //create the event without including the guest
      //var eventObject.colorId = 11
          //var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime1, endTime1, options)
             var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime1, endTime1, options)
             event.setColor("11")
          //CalendarApp.event.setColor("10")
           //var event = calendarEvent.setColor(11);
           //colorId: Red
          }
  return event;   
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even try to set the color... so what is the issue? Do the methods available in the Calendar service not allow you to do exactly what you wish?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does calendarEvent.setColor not work for you?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setColor(String)

In your code above, have you tried adding:

event.setColor(CalendarEvent.EventColor.RED)?

Comment: Thanks! The following got it working.   event.setColor("11")